# How does one convert 1D h5py array-like object filled with tuples to 2d Dask array?

Tags: python, dask, h5py

I am trying to read a dataset from an hdf5 file. The h5py data handle is formatted as a a 1d array

```
    with h5py.File(files[0], 'r') as f:
        flux = f['/nsae']
        print(flux.shape)
        print(flux[:5])
```

```
    (1344,)
    [(b'2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T00:29:59.000Z', 4.95551669)
     (b'2018-02-01T00:30:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T00:59:59.000Z', 1.65919189)
     (b'2018-02-01T01:00:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T01:29:59.000Z', 0.88306412)
     (b'2018-02-01T01:30:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T01:59:59.000Z', 0.97632175)
     (b'2018-02-01T02:00:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T02:29:59.000Z', 0.9270446)]
```

I want to end up with a 3d dask array:

```
    [[b'2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T00:29:59.000Z', 4.95551669]
     [b'2018-02-01T00:30:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T00:59:59.000Z', 1.65919189]
     [b'2018-02-01T01:00:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T01:29:59.000Z', 0.88306412]
     [b'2018-02-01T01:30:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T01:59:59.000Z', 0.97632175]
     [b'2018-02-01T02:00:00.000Z', b'2018-02-01T02:29:59.000Z', 0.9270446]
    ...]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?
Ultimately I will be putting the data from many similar files (and also data from some csv files) into  dask dataframes, concatenating into a single dataframe and then saving as one new hdf5. I am open to skipping the array stage if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: What's the dtype of your hdf5 dataset? It's unusual for a dataset to come back as a list of tuples...

Comment: the type is  "|V58"

Comment: which is raw data (void) it seems. From  [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: `print(flux.dtype)`?  Looks like `arr = flux[:5]` is a 1d 5 element structured array, with 3 fields.  2 are bytes strings which might be convertible to `np.datetime64` and the third is float.  I don't know if `dask` can handle `numpy` structured arrays (compound dtype) or not.  It certainly won't be 3d.

Comment: `print(flux.dtype)` gives  `[('timeBgn', 'S25'), ('timeEnd', 'S25'), ('flux', '<f8')]`

Comment: I can access the columns in flux using 'timeBgn', 'timeEnd', and 'flux', e.g.<br />   ```print(flux['timeBgn'])```

Comment: Actually, the hdf5 data set is accessed similar to a `numpy record array`. It has 1344 rows of `dtype=np.dtype( [('timeBgn', 'S25'), ('timeEnd', 'S25'), ('flux', '<f8')] )`. You can access elements by row(s) with `flux[row_indices]`. Or access all elements in the first field/column with `flux['timeBgn']`. You can also read the data set into  a `np.recarray` with `flux = f['/nsae'][:]` and slice using numpy record array slicing.